# amsmath \intertext works inside the reactions environment but mathtools \shortintertext doesn't

Tags: environments, mathtools, chemmacros

If I typest a set of chemical equations with the *chemmacros* `reactions` environment I can use `\intertext{}` no problem. If I use `\shortintertext{}` it's no good.

**Working MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
  \chemsetup{modules = all}
  \chemsetup{formula = chemformula}

\begin{document}
  This works:
  \begin{reactions}
    A + 2 B2 ->& 3 C3 + 4 D4
    \intertext{and}
    W + 2 X2 ->& 3 Y3 + 4 Z4
  \end{align}
\end{reactions}
```

**Not Working MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
  \chemsetup{modules = all}
  \chemsetup{formula = chemformula}

\begin{document}
  This doesn't work:
  \begin{reactions}
    A + 2 B3 ->& 3 C4 + 5 D6 
    \shortintertext{and}
    W + 2 X2 ->& 3 Y3 + 4 Z4
  \end{reactions}
\end{document}
```

If I switch to the `align` environment that `reactions` is based on then I can use `\shortintertext{}` no problems.

**Working MWE, but no `reactions` goodness**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
  \chemsetup{modules = all}
  \chemsetup{formula = chemformula}

\begin{document}
  However, this works:
  \begin{align}
    \ch{A + 2 B3 ->& 3 C4 + 5 D6}
    \shortintertext{and}
    \ch{W + 2 X2 ->& 3 Y3 + 4 Z4}
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure if i'm using chemmacros or mathtools incorrectly. I'd like to use `\shortintertext` from the mathtools package for it's tighter spacing.

Comment: `\shortintertext` support just isn't implemented in `chemformula` – it's not `chemmacros`' fault. You can make a feature request: https://github.com/cgnieder/chemformula/issues/new

Comment: Ok, that would be excellent. I'll get on it. I also have a suggestion for a new bond-type too. I have that all working. I'll send you the code as per the documentation.

Comment: `chemformula` has been updated, this should work now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is due to a missing feature of a package (which has now been added which makes the issue dissappear; the answer is now: update your distribution)